# KERNAL DRIVER Ошибка компиляции

Tags: c, windows, драйвер

я только недавно начал изучать не судите строго переписываю по видео просто кто бы помог объяснил что до как я видимо совсем тугой заранее спасибо

[ссылка на видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eumG222Efzs)

**вывод компилятора**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Ошибка C2371 PETHREAD: переопределение; различные базовые типы

> Ошибка C2371 PEPROCESS: переопределение; различные базовые типы

**Events.c**

```
#include "Events.h"
#include "Messages.h"
#include "Data.h"

PLOAD_IMAGE_NOTIFY_ROUTINE ImageLoadCallback(PUNICODE_STRING FullImageName, HANDLE ProcessId, PIMAGE_INFO ImageInfo)
{
    //DebugMessage("[ Driver ]>INFO ImageLoad: %ls /n", FullImageName->Buffer);

    if (wcsstr(FullImageName->Buffer, L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamclient.dll"))
    {
        DebugMessage("[ Driver ]>INFO steamclient.dll: FOUND \n",);
        ClientAddress = ImageInfo->ImageBase;

        DebugMessage("[ Driver ]>ProcessId: %d \n", ProcessId);
    } 
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Events.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <ntifs.h>

PLOAD_IMAGE_NOTIFY_ROUTINE ImageLoadCallback(PUNICODE_STRING FullImageName, HANDLE ProcessId, PIMAGE_INFO ImageInfo);
```

**Data.h**

```
#pragma once 

#include <ntdef.h>

ULONG ClientAddress;
```

**Main.c**

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4100 4065 4013)

#include "Main.h"
#include "Events.h"
#include "Messages.h"

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) 
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    DebugMessage("[ Driver ]>LOAD");

    PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine(ImageLoadCallback);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);

    DebugMessage("[ Driver ]>UNLOAD");

    PsRemoveLoadImageNotifyRoutine(ImageLoadCallback);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Это вывод компилятора или всякий там IntelliSense? Покажите вывод компилятора.

Comment: Да как я понял вводит компилятор
[Фотку покрепил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgG9R.png)

Comment: Это не компилятор. Найдите вывод компилятоа (окно Output) и добавьте его к вопросу текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Добавил окно вывода

Comment: #include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h> они могут конфликтовать ?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь похожие проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580129/cant-include-wdm-h-and-ntifs-h-in-the-same-file   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854835/simple-kernel-mode-driver   https://community.osr.com/discussion/210899/error-c2371-peprocess-redefinition

Comment: Спасибо решило мою проблему